# Rest Services on custom localhost Path on Jboss 6.4

Tags: java, jboss, redhat, jboss6.x

I did a change in the deployment scanner of my Jboss 6.4 with the idea to change the path :

standalone.xml

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
                    <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000"/>
                    <deployment-scanner name="MYWAR" path="usr\MYWAR\deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-enabled="true" scan-interval="5000" auto-deploy-zipped="false" auto-deploy-exploded="false" deployment-timeout="60"/>
    </subsystem>
```

I can deploy without problems and it works, but the problem appears when I try to execute my rest services: I got a error 404. I cannot find any indication as to the source of the problem in the server log.

The same war in another jboss 6.4 with the default deployment path works perfectly.

Log:

```
13:42:41,228 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015003: mywar.war in Deployment-Verzeichnis gefunden. Um Deployment zustarten, erstellen Sie eine Datei namens mywar.war.dodeploy
13:42:44,721 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starte Deployment von "DocumenzCarlos" (runtime-name: "mywar")
13:42:44,783 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 18) JBAS015859: "mywar" deployed (runtime-name: "mywar")
```

standalone.xml

```
 <deployments>
        <deployment name="mywar" runtime-name="mywar.war">
            <fs-archive path="usr\mywar\deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir"/>
        </deployment>
    </deployments>
```

Any Idea where is the conflict?

Comment: auto-deploy-zipped="true" with this works :)